# Using Metro, Netbeans, and Tomcat7 for web services

Tags: web-services, netbeans, tomcat7, java-metro-framework

I have two related questions:

(1) What is the "correct" way to place various Metro files in Tomcat 7/JDK directories? It seems that the automated procedure provided with Metro has not been updated for Tomcat 7.

(2) Is there a way to create a web service using Metro & Netbeans, and transfering the NetBeans generated .war file to Tomcat 7 WITHOUT editing any .xml file?

I have to use NetBeans 7.x and Tomcat 7.x. I can use any version of Metro.

It would seem that such an elementary question would have a readily available answer on the web, but even the tutorial on the NetBeans site seems to be broken.

Thanks!

Comment: Prasoon, I am looking for the same thing you asked. Can you please share the solution you found for this.

Answer (score 1):

> Q: What is the "correct" way to place various Metro files in Tomcat 7/JDK
>   directories?  It seems that the automated procedure provided with
>   Metro has not been updated for Tomcat 7.

You are right, procedure hasn't been updated for Tomcat7. Never the less, you can use it without any problem, it will create two directories in CATALINA_HOME directory:

`/endorsed` (it will put there `webservices-api.jar`)

`/shared/lib` (it will put there `webservices-extra-api.jar, webservices-extra.jar, webservices-rt.jar` and `webservices-tools.jar`)

> Q: Is there a way to create a web service using Metro & Netbeans, and
>   transfering the NetBeans generated .war file to Tomcat 7 WITHOUT
>   editing any .xml file?

Usually, you should edit web.xml and sun-jaxws.xml. However, because you're using Tomcat 7 which is Servlet 3.0 container, web.xml is unneccessary and you only have to deal with sun-jaxws.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoints xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime" version="2.0">
<endpoint
      name="SERVICE_NAME"
      implementation="full.qualified.name.of.the.implementation.class"
      url-pattern="/SERVICE_URL"/>
</endpoints>
```

Additionally, you have to place sun-jaxws.xml in WEB-INF directory.

See also:

- [JAX-WS RI web services deployment made simplified](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/ramapulavarthi/archive/2010/08/13/jax-ws-ri-web-services-deployment-made-simplified)

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer your two questions directly, instead I can tell you how I resolved the problem.

I've used [this easy tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/deploy-jax-ws-web-services-on-tomcat/) to install the jax-ws libraries in tomcat (without Netbeans). I didn't copy the jars into the $TOMCAT/lib directory, I copied them to the WEB-INF/lib directory inside the web-app itself. The rest is pretty much the same as he described in the tutorial and it works.

Now to your questions:

(1) I don't know how it should be done the "correct" way. But I think when it works some way it can't be that wrong. I'm sure there are best practices for deploying the libs, but I just don't know them. Sorry.

(2) Unfortunately I don't use Netbeans, so I can't help you here either. But If you think about it, I have copied all the libs from the jax-ws reference implementation to my WEB-INF/lib directory and I haven't touched any XML other than those in my WEB-INF directory. Now I could create a war file from my web-app and I'm done. There shouldn't be any big difference to Netbeans I think.

I hope that helps.